# What fluent api method is correspond to [Timestamp] attribute in Data Annotations API to check concurrency

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I am using Entity Framework 4.1.
What fluent api method is correspond to [Timestamp] attribute in Data Annotations API to check concurrency?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you have class like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    ...
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

You will use fluent mapping like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
            .Property(e => e.Timestamp)
            .IsConcurrencyToken()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
```

Or:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
            .Property(e => e.Timestamp)
            .IsRowVersion();
```

Comment: IsConcurrencyToken() method corresponds to ConcurrencyCheck attribute, isn't it?

Comment: Yes you are right. I modified answer - first will work as well but the second is how the `TimestampAttribute` is translated.

Comment: Thank you Ladislav, that is what I want

Comment: @LadislavMrnka it has some differences, look at my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can use code as Ladislav Mrnka described, but

There are small differences between :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
            .Property(e => e.Timestamp)
            .IsConcurrencyToken()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
            .Property(e => e.Timestamp)
            .IsRowVersion();
```

second is equivalent of `[Timestamp]` attribute, but first generates the following migration, when we change '[Timestamp]` to first version of fluent API code:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.MyEntity", "Timestamp", c => c.Binary());
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.MyEntity", "Timestamp", c => c.Binary(nullable: false, fixedLength: true, timestamp: true, storeType: "rowversion"));
    }
```